# Swift UITableView won't programmatically scroll to bottom after adding new cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, chat, ios9, xcode7

I am building a pretty basic chat app where users can send messages back and forth. When a user sends a message I currently sync the data with parse and then call an updateMessages()

> func updateMessages() {
>
> ```
>    let messageQuery = Message.query()
>    messageQuery.whereKey("contThread", equalTo: >selectedThread.objectId!)
>    messageQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) ->> Void in
>        if error == nil {
>            if let objects = objects as? [Message] {
>                print(objects.count)
>                print("FLAG")
>                messages = objects
>                self.messageTable.reloadData()
>                print(messages.count)
>                self.scrollToBottom()
>            }
>        }
>    }
> ```
>
> }

function that pulls the updated data from parse and repopulates the messages table. I would like the tableView to programmatically scroll to the bottom after the message table is repopulated, and cannot understand why calling scrollToBottom()

> func scrollToBottom() {
>
> ```
>    if messageTable.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) != nil {
>        messageTable.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: messages.count-1 , inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: >false)
>    }
> ```
>
> }

at the end of my updateMessages() function doesn't work. Any/all suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to update into main queue?

Comment: It seems you are doing `scrollToBottom` in background queue?